# sprintf not functioning correctly when concatenating an int and string

Tags: c, file, printf

I have the following code (in a server [sender] program):

```
#define PAYLOAD 256

//...some more code...

    int l;
    char packet[PAYLOAD];
    char seqNumNpacket[sizeof(l) + sizeof(packet) + 1]; //to account for the number, space and the packet

    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen(req, "r");
    l = 0;        
    char seqNumNpacket[sizeof(l) + sizeof(packet) + 1];
    //... some more code...
    n = fread(packet, 1, PAYLOAD, fp2);
    packet[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s", packet);
    sprintf(seqNumNpacket, "%d %s", l, packet);
    printf("%d %s", seqNumNpacket); //A
```

Here I am trying to read bytes from a file, and then put it together in a string with a number so that I can send it over to other process using `sendto()`/`recvfrom`.

The problem arises when I use `sprintf` to stick them together. Somehow instead of writing a string of the fashion of "`seqNum`  `packet`" it ends up as "`seqNum`  `packet` `seqNUm`".

I have no clue what is causing this and thus haven't found a way to solve it. Thanks for the help beforehand with this *silly* question.

Comment: `sizeof(l)` has nothing to do with the number of characters the strnig representation of the integer will have. Also, don't mix declarations with statements and don't `fread()` before checking if `fp2 == NULL`.

Comment: I did it because by default it's 4 bytes, which saves me trouble of trying to guess how many characters will `l` have, which makes it easier at the moment of concatenating. Still not too sure how that changes things. Thanks on the other suggestions for coding style.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, `10000` could be represented with a 32bit integer and it has more than 4 characters, the number of bytes an integer uses has nothing to do with the number of bytes it's string representation will need.

Comment: If you don't know up front how much space to allocate, you can use snprintf instead of sprintf, and it will tell you how many characters you need.  Then you can allocate the buffer, and then call snprintf again with the correct size buffer.

Comment: Exactly `snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d %s",  l, packet);` will return the number of characters you need without the `'\0'` terminator, and if you are on linux you can use `asprintf()` which allocates space for the target string.

Comment: `fread` returns the number of items read. Not the number of bytes read.

Comment: @iharob I guess I will get to read on `asprintf()` see how it works. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @kaylum Which is the number of bytes in this case, but I do think that it was important to point out.

Comment: @iharob Yes you are right. I had the params swapped around in my head. But in that case, I guess OP is overflowing `packet` since `n` is set to `PAYLOAD` on success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The most important problem with your code is this

   ```
   n = fread(packet, 1, PAYLOAD, fp2);
   ```

   even though you are using it right, the next line

   ```
   packet[n] = '\0';
   ```

   can be wrong, because if `n == PAYLOAD` this would write 1 byte after the end of the `packet` array, you should read like this

   ```
   n = fread(packet, 1, PAYLOAD - 1, fp2);
   ```

   If you fix this, the problem might go away because it appears that the `packet` array has no `'\0'` terminator from your result.
2. The second very important problem, is using `sizeof(int)` for the string representation of an integer.

Comment: or if the full size of the payload might be important, increase buffer size by 1

Comment: @M.M I think I might do that
@iharob Thanks a lot. I modified it accordingly using `asprintf` and it worked ^_^ may the force be with you.